# DateTime in PropertyGrid in .Net

Tags: datetime, propertygrid

I'm currently working on some DateTime properties in a PropertyGrid in c#.Net. Im using the default drop-down datetime picker.

My question: Is there any way to show the full date with the time? By default the date is shown if no time is set, but I want zero-values aswell. I.e: I want "09.11.2009 00:00" to be shown instead of "09.11.2009".

Do I have to use some custom TypeConverter or Editor for this?
I feel so lost in this propertygrid and it makes me sad...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to have a time picker displayed in the dropdown as well.  I'd like the user to be able to easily enter both date and time without typing it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need your own TypeConverter. Derive it from DateTimeConverter and override the ConvertTo method. If you look this method in Reflector you will see this piece of code inside:

```
if (time.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0.0)
    return time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

Just remove that for example.

Nicolas